# what does the "Throw" Keyword, used on its own, actually do

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I've been asked to add some error handling on the socket layer of an application i'm working on and am frequently coming across older bits of code where the "Throw" keyword is being used on its own. for example:

```
Try
    'lots of code in here
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
End Try
```

I thought when using the Throw keyword you had to use it as part of a statement e.g:

```
Throw New NotSupportedException("message for the exception", variable.ToString())
```

I've just never seen it used on its own before and couldn't find any simple explanation online, so i thought i'd throw it out on here and see what people think. chances are its some poor/incomplete coding from previous developers but i wanted to know if it served any purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: If the exception is being caught further up then throw without parameters should be used to preserve the call stack information.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Throw` without specifying the exception inside a `try ... catch` statement. Its purpose is to allow you to rethrow the exception.

Have a look at the [Throw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you asked for the purpose of ***throw***:
[image: ![The Throw statement resets the call stack for the expression exception]]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When we use *throw* in *catch* block, it means of as a **rethrow—it** means throws the same exception already being handled (throw statement with no argument).
see below snippets, in which we can use *throw* in different ways

1.

```
try
{
    int iCount = 100 / 0;
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Here we are **rethrowing** the exception (re-throw cause catch already throw exception to Catch block)

2.

```
try
{
     int iCount = 100 / 0;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

This is not a rethrow, it just throws the same exception but with stack trace (object ex), here we can collect more information about exception

3.

```
 try
{
     string szApp = "Application";
         throw new Exception("custom exception");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Here we throw custom exception and break program control

Comment: Would be best to post code examples in vb.net rather than C# as the question was asked for vb.net